# android-pdf-viewer Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, pdf-viewer

I'm trying to implement the AndroidPDFViewer in a JeckPack Compouse Android app. I get this error "Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized". I already added to the settings.gradle.kts file " maven { url = uri("https://jitpack.io") }" and in the build.gradle.kts file is the implementation " implementation("com.github.barteksc: android-pdf-viewer:1.6.0")
"

I'm trying to get the PDFViewer implemented, it doesn't give me an error.

Comment: If you are getting that error from the library, it is because you are requesting a PDF from a server that requires a login or some similar form of authentication.